# Download pdf from href link issue

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, download

I am working on a wordpress. I make a meta field for upload pdf file,pdf file upload sucessfully. Now i call meta value in href link for download the pdf file.But the problem is that it can open the file but not download.For this i search a code that is

```
<?php  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$event_flyer");
?>
```

$event_flyer is used for accessing meta value.

but its not working for specific href its just working for whole page on refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your pdf file to be downloadable by anyone who could browse your website just by clicking on links, then you can use the `download` attribute (for  tags) which allows you to specify the linked resource :

Doc here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Just remember that browser compatibility for the download attribute is not great yet: [caniuse.com/#feat=download](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you have a reader installed it will always open instead of  downloading. 
If you have hosted your wordpress on a live server then you can try to open link on a PC where PDF reader is not installed. It will download the file instead of opening.

Answer (score 0):

You need more code, check this:

`header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$pathtopdf");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
readfile($pathtopdf);`

Comment: where should to use this code in header.php or function.php